# How to repair apt / auto upgrades?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, unattended-upgrades, ncurses

I was trying to look at the differences between the two files that unattended upgrades was asking me about. And while resizing the windows, I accidentally hit to keep the old file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist`. Now I get this message whenever I install a software package :

```
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open a terminal and execute : `sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist`
The command **removes the unneeded file** and the informational message will not appear any longer when you are running `sudo apt update` or when you install new software packages.

Comment: it's `sudo apt-get update`, not `sudo apt update` !

Comment: @arximughal : As of the Ubuntu 16.10 release the apt command is the default command ... apt-get was the default command until Ubuntu 16.04 ! :)

Comment: I surely didn't knew about that. Thanks for the comment back @cl-netbox